# 06:00 displays as 00:25 in userform

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to retrieve time information from a spreadsheet on to a userform, but i'm coming across an issue where 06:00:00 is displayed as 00:25:00. The spreadsheet is used for time calculations to do with company Flexi time and we're trying to simplify and limit the user interface by using a userform. It also changes 12:00:00 to 00:05:00. Is there any way of getting this to display the correct time?

This is the code we are currently using to display the info.

```
Private Sub TimeCheck_Change()
    If Left(TimeCheck.Text, 1) = "-" Then
    TimeCheck.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
    TimeCheck.Text = Format(TimeCheck.Text, "hh:Nn;(hh:Nn)")

End Sub
```

this ties the Textbox to the sheet:

```
Private Sub cmdsearch_Click()


    row_number = 0
    Do
    DoEvents
    row_number = row_number + 1
    Status = Sheets("Flex Total").Range("A" & row_number)
    If Status = EmployeeCheck.Text Then
    TimeowedCheck.Value = Sheets("Flex Total").Range("B" & row_number)
    timetakenCheck.Value = Sheets("Flex Total").Range("C" & row_number)
    TimeCheck.Value = Sheets("Flex Total").Range("D" & row_number)
    End If
    Loop Until Status = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: try "mm" instead of "Nn"

Comment: I tried that to start with adn it didn't work. I changed it to Nn after reading some blogs regarding a similar issue.

Comment: Could be a system locale issue?? I'm not able to replicate it (both example values work as expected when I test this).

Comment: Where is the initial value for `TimeCheck.Text` coming from -- can you show the code that assigns that from the worksheet? And indicate what value is present on the worksheet?

Comment: I've checked all settings and properties. Nothing seems to affect the problem. On the spreadsheet the information is displayed as number format i.e. 06:00:00 is 0.25, but even changing this to time format on the spreadsheet doesn't seem to affect the way it is displayed on the userform. It still shows it as 00:25:00

Comment: TimeCheck.Text   is reference to the TextBox on the userform where the information is displayed

Comment: On the spreadsheet, then, the `.Value` is .25, and that is your problem. Changing the cell's `.NumberFormat` does not alter its underlying *value* property.

Comment: Can you show your code that assigns the spreadsheet value to the TextBox? I know how to fix this, but I would like to see what you're doing so that I don't give you wrong advice.

Comment: I've edited the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, this line assigns the value from spreadsheet:

```
TimeCheck.Value = Sheets("Flex Total").Range("D" & row_number)
```

Equivalent to:

```
TimeCheck.Value = Sheets("Flex Total").Range("D" & row_number).Value
```

The cell is a `Range` object, and its *default property* is its `.Value`.  This property will be returned unless you specify another property instead.  As in your case, the *value* is 0.25, changing the `NumberFormat` property will not help.

Instead, try:

```
TimeCheck.Value = Sheets("Flex Total").Range("D" & row_number).Text
```

This will use the cell's `.Text` property instead of the `.Value`, and the `.Text` property is affected by the `NumberFormat` change you have made, so I think that should fix it.